# Catch jaxb unmarshal exception of the binding object

Tags: validation, exception, jaxb, cxf, unmarshalling

I use the jaxb of the cxf to unmarshall the xml request.

I am looking for a way to validate the input xml request, I had read the following two super articles about the validation, but they are not exactly what I need.

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Actually, instead of stopping right away the whole unmarshalling process and giving the exception message back in the response, I need the unmarshalling process keep running, and be able to link the exception with the object whose xml element is not validated. In this way, the application can still do the next jobs on the other well unmarshalled objects except this one, at the end in the returned xml response, I can show the exception message for this particular object, as well as the good results for the other objects.

Is that possible?

any help is really appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

You can set an instance of [`ValidationEventCollector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/util/ValidationEventCollector.html) on the `Unmarshaller`.  It will store all instances of `ValidationEvent` encontered during the unmarshal.  After the `unmarshal` operation if it has collected any events then you can choose to thrown an `Exception`.

BTW, I'm happy to hear that you enjoyed those posts.

Comment: thank you for your response and your super articles, I will try it out.

Comment: can ValidationEventCollector tell on which object it gets the exception? 
for example, like the xml below, can validationEventCollector tell the birthday date format of the first person is not correct?

<persons>
<person name="first">
<birthday>fadsfdas</birthday> 
</person>
<person name="first">
<birthday>12/02/2012</birthday> 
</person>
</persons>